# Remove a certain number of characters after a certain character

Tags: php, substr

I'm looking for a way to remove a character from a string and remove also just the next 2 characters after the specified character.

I found here this method that remove the specified character and everything after it, but I don't think that the substr function will do what I need.

```
$variable = substr($variable, 0, strpos($variable, "By"));
```

For example, I have a string with this content:

```
/path/shop.php?category=ab&page=xy
```

Specifying `?category=` will remove `?category=` and `ab`.

Without the use of str_replace (because I can't specify `ab`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `preg_replace` and `preg_quote` function:

```
$str = '/path/shop.php?category=ab&page=xy';
$v = '?category=';
$result = preg_replace("/". preg_quote($v) .".{2}/", "", $str);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
/path/shop.php&page=xy
```

---

`.{2}` - points to the next 2 characters after specified search substring

Answer (score 0):

Just get 2 substrings:

```
$position = strpos($fullString, $removable);
$sub1 = substr($fullstring, 0, $position);
$sub2 = substr($fullstring, 
$position + strlen($removable), 
strlen($fullstring) -($position + strlen($removable)));

$finalString = $sub1 + $sub2;
```